# Predix: No module named _tkinter

Tags: python, heroku, matplotlib, cloud-foundry, predix

I am trying to push a Python Microservice on Predix.
The code is having `matplotlib` dependency.

`cf push` fails for the app with following stack trace.

```
2017-05-08T19:39:51.43+0530 [App/0]      ERR Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-05-08T19:39:51.43+0530 [App/0]      ERR   File "server.py", line 7, in <module>
2017-05-08T19:39:51.43+0530 [App/0]      ERR     from services.testService import TestServiceOptimalFrequencyForward as TestService
2017-05-08T19:39:51.43+0530 [App/0]      ERR   File "/home/vcap/app/services/testService.py", line 12, in <module>
2017-05-08T19:39:51.43+0530 [App/0]      ERR     from models import test
2017-05-08T19:39:51.43+0530 [App/0]      ERR   File "/home/vcap/app/models/test.py", line 5, in <module>
2017-05-08T19:39:51.43+0530 [App/0]      ERR     from models import model1, model2, model3, pvt
2017-05-08T19:39:51.43+0530 [App/0]      ERR   File "/home/vcap/app/models/model2.py", line 23, in <module>
2017-05-08T19:39:51.43+0530 [App/0]      ERR     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
2017-05-08T19:39:51.43+0530 [App/0]      ERR   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
2017-05-08T19:39:51.43+0530 [App/0]      ERR   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
2017-05-08T19:39:51.43+0530 [App/0]      ERR     globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
2017-05-08T19:39:51.43+0530 [App/0]      ERR   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 6, in <module>
2017-05-08T19:39:51.43+0530 [App/0]      ERR     _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
2017-05-08T19:39:51.43+0530 [App/0]      ERR     from six.moves import tkinter as Tk
2017-05-08T19:39:51.43+0530 [App/0]      ERR   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 203, in load_module
2017-05-08T19:39:51.43+0530 [App/0]      ERR     mod = mod._resolve()
2017-05-08T19:39:51.43+0530 [App/0]      ERR   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
2017-05-08T19:39:51.43+0530 [App/0]      ERR     return _import_module(self.mod)
2017-05-08T19:39:51.43+0530 [App/0]      ERR   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
2017-05-08T19:39:51.43+0530 [App/0]      ERR     __import__(name)
2017-05-08T19:39:51.43+0530 [App/0]      ERR   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
2017-05-08T19:39:51.43+0530 [App/0]      ERR     import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
2017-05-08T19:39:51.43+0530 [App/0]      ERR ImportError: No module named _tkinter
2017-05-08T19:39:51.53+0530 [App/0]      OUT 
2017-05-08T19:39:51.57+0530 [DEA/55]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
```

I am using `python_buildpack`.

Thanks in advance, for any help in resolving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python build pack has support for using the Conda package manager instead of `pip`.  You might want to give this a try.

http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/python/#miniconda

Using that, I was able to deploy this sample application which uses Matplotlib to CF.

https://github.com/ihuston/python-cf-examples/tree/master/02-pydata-spyre-app

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are running Linux do
sudo apt-get install python-tk

Maybe you have to recompile Python afterwards.

Comment: The suggested way is not possible since cloud Foundry doesn't allow us to do any installs.